# Eliminating csv file rows if specific string is not present

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to compile a database of medical school interview questions and scraped a lot of data onto a csv file. Column 0 contains the school name, and Column 1 contains the entry.

Some of the entries to the CSV are comments about medical schools rather than self-reported interview questions. Is there any way to eliminate entire rows in the csv file that do not meet the criteria of an interview question?

The four conditions on which I would like to eliminate entries are if the entry does not contain "?", "Explain", "Define", or "Tell me".

Sample question_data.csv

```
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,None-very laid back.
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,What were your favorite three classes in college?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,Do you believe that doctors should treat everyone regardless of ability to pay?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,None were too difficult.
Duke University School of Medicine,"If you were the Dean of the med school, what one thing would you ensure the students knew when they graduated from DukeMed? "
Duke University School of Medicine,"If you were interviewing me (the interviewer), what would you ask?"
Duke University School of Medicine,Nothing too interesting
```

I have code that can print a random entry from the csv. file, but am unable to filter out non-question entries. This is why I am seeking to edit the csv instead:

```
import random
import csv
import pandas as pd

csv_file = "question_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, names=["College", "Question"])
modified_df = df.dropna()
df_question = modified_df.groupby("College")["Question"]

school_selection = input('Please enter the name of a college: ')
random_question = generateRandomQuestion(modified_df,school_selection)
print(random_question)
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yes, Franco. Just updated the post with what I had previously tried. Since my function has no way of filtering the entries, I think I might be better off just editing the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `contains` to return only the rows that contain the specified words.

```py
modified_df = modified_df[modified_df['Question'].str.contains('\?|Explain|Define|Tell me')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Where should I input this line of code?

Comment: I've updated the answer, it returns the filtered dataframe to the existing dataframe.

Comment: When I input this into my code, I get an error on the line preceding it that says the following: 

df_question = modified_df.groupby("College")["Question"]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Don't know how but a closing ] went missing when I last changed the answer - I've updated it, tested it with your entire code and it works.